# table not created

Tags: android-sqlite

The project executes but table is not created. My codes

```
{
public HelperData(Context context) {

        super(context, database_name, null, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String creat = "Create table " + Table_name + "(" + KEY_ID
                + " Integer primary key autoincrement," + KEY_FNAME + "TEXT,"
                + KEY_LNAME + "TEXT" + ");";
        Log.d("Tag", "==table created" + creat);
        db.execSQL(creat);
}
}
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what the content of those Strings (like `KEY_FNAME` or `KEY_LNAME`) is but it appears you don't have a space between the strings that define the column names and their data types.

E.g.:

If `String KEY_LNAME = "something"`,

`KEY_LNAME + "TEXT"` can result in something like "somethingTEXT" instead of "something TEXT".

If that is the case, you can either add a space to the end of the column name string (e.g. `String KEY_LNAME = "something "`) or add the space before the column data type (... `KEY_LNAME + " TEXT"` ...).

Also, look at Logcat, there may be some Exceptions being thrown.

I may be wrong, as I don't know what those strings of yours contain, but that's my guess.